# get_iPlayer problems on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, iplayer

I have checked other posts for this error messages and I cannot find a solution.

I have get_iPlayer installed on an old Windows7 machine and it works OK. Upon installing on a new computer I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\get_iplayer>get_iplayer "http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/epi
sode/b03696ww/America_this_Week_23_06_2013/"
get_iplayer v2.83, Copyright (C) 2008-2010 Phil Lewis
  This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details use --warranty.
  This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain
  conditions; use --conditions for details.

INFO: Episode-only pid detected
INFO: Trying pid: b03696ww using type: tv
INFO Trying to stream pid using type tv
INFO: pid found in cache
Matches:
52:     America this Week - 23/06/2013, BBC Parliament, Factual,News,Politics,TV
, default,

INFO: 1 Matching Programmes
INFO: Checking existence of default version
INFO: flashvhigh1,flashvhigh2,flashhigh1,flashhigh2,flashstd1,flashstd2,flashlow
1,flashlow2 modes will be tried for version default
INFO: Trying flashvhigh1 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashvhigh1 mode
INFO: Trying flashvhigh2 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashvhigh2 mode
INFO: Trying flashhigh1 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashhigh1 mode
INFO: Trying flashhigh2 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashhigh2 mode
INFO: Trying flashstd1 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashstd1 mode
INFO: Trying flashstd2 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashstd2 mode
INFO: Trying flashlow1 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashlow1 mode
INFO: Trying flashlow2 mode to record tv: America this Week - 23/06/2013
INFO: File name prefix = America_this_Week_-_23_06_2013_b03696ww_default

WARNING: Your version of rtmpdump/flvstreamer does not support SWF Verification
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade
INFO: skipping flashlow2 mode
ERROR: Failed to record 'America this Week - 23/06/2013 (b03696ww)'

C:\Program Files (x86)\get_iplayer>
```

So far I have tried the following:

- Uninstalling / deleting all traces of get_iplayer, reinstalling again
- Downloaded different installer: get_iplayer_setup_latest.exe from infradead.com
- Tried downloading different episodes to see if it was an episode specific problem

I am running 64bit Windows 7, installed clean recently.

Comment: The warning seems to be clear enough. Are you saying the same URL works with the same (or older) version of get_iplayer installed on the other PC?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your path as follows:

1- open command prompt as admin.

2- add the following in it and then press enter:

set PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%path%;

3- open get_iplayer and type: path and hit enter. (it will show your path string), make sure the new path is displayed. if not then

open control panel, system, 'advanced system settings' then click on 'advanced' tab, click on 'environment variables' button.
select path from the list and click on edit.
then add this to the beginning of the string (DO NOT DELETE THE EXISTING STRING):

C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

click 'OK' and exit the settings. test your new path by typing path in the get_iplayer command window.
you may need to reboot your system.

Good luck, Saeid.

Comment: I had the same problem on my Win7 pc, and it was fixed by adding the path string stated above. the get_iplayer uses many components. although the Get_iplayer itself starts without an error the dependent component will fail to run correctly without the above path string. if you don't have any first hand experience in this matter then don't dismiss what others suggest from their own experience.